# How exactly does Tomcat's Threadpool work

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, threadpool

So here's my understanding.

The Apache Tomcat's threadpool (is it called the connector Threadpool? ) has a number of threads ( 200 by default ). Now this means that at a particular time, 200 people can communicate with my web application.

Now, taking a scenario when a particular connects with my application. I get a request, and the tomcat client on the server checks if there is any thread available to cater to the request or not. If it is then good, else we give back some error code. Now in case of success, will that one thread, that I have assigned to that request, be associated with that particular client till the time his request is not handled?

Basically, as a user if I go to, `www.myApp.com`, I get one thread from the thread pool that fetches all the info from the server and gives me back the final html. After that the thread is free and goes back to pool. Now if I click on something else then again go to the threadpool and get assigned a thread if available and it goes on a on. Is this how it works?

Question 2

Let's say, I have a Java Application on my server side. So when I hit a url, it takes me to some java code. Now is it that, the thread that I got from Tomcat Threadpool, that thread will execute my code?

If that is so, what happens if I make new threads in my java code, will those threads be taken from the Tomcat's threadpool or will those be from the Java's threadpool created? Also, what happens to the execution of the Tomcat's thread in that case?

Thanks.

Kindly provide some Tomcat official references/resources where I can read about such things if you know about any. Cheers.

Comment: 1. Yes, your understanding is conceptually correct. 2. That thread will execute your code. If you make a new thread it has nothing to do with Tomcat's thread pool. Tomcat's thread continues running as per usual.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Don't forget that not all tasks are CPU bound. The number of people that can connect "concurrently" is not 100% connected to the number of CPU threads that can run concurrently. Also we typically use the word "concurrent" even when referring to multiple threads on the same core.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson When you say that there is no such thing as Java Threadpool, what exactly are you suggesting. What will be the more apt term for the same. I meant the Threadpool created by my Java Application.

Comment: @Kraken He's correctly suggesting that there's no such thing as a general "Java thread pool". Tomcat manages a thread pool by creating 200 threads and using them as a thread pool. Other threads you create in Java are just... threads. They're limited by OS resources, for the most part. A "thread pool" is an actual thing that you implement, it's not just a general term that refers to a bunch of threads.

Comment: @Kraken See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern

Comment: See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/executor.html. If the 200 threads are busy, the 201th client connecting won't be rejected. It will block waiting until a thread becomes available.

Comment: @JasonC Yeah, I meant the Executor in Java. My bad.

Comment: @JasonC I have one last question, (I will make the edits to the above question) , for the AJAX requests, does it use one thread per request from Tomcat's threadpool?

Comment: @Kraken: AJAX requests are no different from other HTTP requests.

Comment: @JasonC *asynchronously* is **not** the same thing as **concurrent**, the two things are being conflated to mean the same thing by beginners and it does them a dis-service to continue to confuse them with trying to explain *what you mean* rather than use appropriate semantics that are already in place. 4 core system can only service 4 clients **concurrently**, it can service thousands or tens of thousands **asynchronously** with **non-blocking I/O** on a single thread without any **concurrency**.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson The differences between the two terms are irrelevant to the question, as the OP did not use either of them. Also, it is clear what the OP is asking.

Comment: *Now this means that at a particular time, 200 people can communicate with my web application.* demonstrates a fundamental incorrect assumption about *concurrency* based on the number of threads in the pool, which is continued and reinforced in the comments and answers to this question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Now this means that at a particular time, 200 people can communicate with my web application.

Not exactly.  It means that your server can *process* 200 requests simultaneously<sup>1</sup>.   There can be a number of other requests in the queue waiting for a thread to become available.

> Now in case of success, will that one thread, that I have assigned to that request, be associated with that particular client till the time his request is not handled?

Yes ... unless you are using the asynchronous request handling features added in a recent version of the Servlet spec.  (In that case, it may be possible to process more than 200 requests "simultaneously" with 200 threads.  But that would entail one request surrendering control to another request while it waits for something to happen.  Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/servlets012.htm) for introduction.)

> Is this how it works?

More or less ...

<sup>1 - To be pedantic, you would (probably) need 200+ cores for the processing of 200 requests to happen at the same instant in time.  So, I'm using "simultaneously" from the perspective of the end-users, who have no visibility of what is actually happening inside the server "black box".  But having said that, it is not impossible for one physical thread / core to be performing work for multiple requests at the same instant in time.  The most obvious case is where there are lots of identical requests that are handled together.</sup>

---

> Let's say, I have a Java Application on my server side. So when I hit a url, it takes me to some java code. Now is it that, the thread that I got from Tomcat Threadpool, that thread will execute my code?

This doesn't make sense.  If you have a Java application on the server side, then you need to explain *how* you go from an HTTP request ("hitting[sic] a url") to running the Java application.  Only then can we tell you whether or not a threadpool thread is involved.

> If that is so, what happens if I make new threads in my java code, will those threads be taken from the Tomcat's threadpool or will those be from the Java's threadpool created? Also, what happens to the execution of the Tomcat's thread in that case?

Once again, it depends how your Java application is being run.  For instance, if your webapp is using `Runtime.exec("java ... classname")` to run the application on the server-side, then it is in a separate JVM to your Tomcat, and none of the application threads will be in the Tomcat thread pool.

It has also been pointed out that there is no "Java threadpool" *per se*.  If your Java application chooses to, it can create and use a thread pool.  But if it doesn't, then Java threads are not pooled.  They are largely disposed of when they terminate, and any remaining data structures are reclaimed when the `Thread` object is garbage collected.